# Preserving original text formatting in sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a prepopulated sqlite database which is located in my assets folder. I have created this prepopulated database using sqlite studio. Now, I have a notepad file which contains a lot of paragraphs and lines break etc. What I want to do is store the same text formatting that I have in notepad to be preserve in sqlite database.

So, what I did was I just copy the text from the notepad and paste it into sqlite database. However, when I fetched the data into View in android like listview or textview, all the text just appear as one single paragraph with not paragraph which is not what I want. I want to preserve the same formatting that I have in notepad and I only want to use sqlite database. So, how can I solve the  issue?

But, one thing what I have notice is that, whatever I type such text with paragraph on TextEditor in android and then store it and then fetch the data back it appears exaclty the same.

Comment: `\n`, `\r` and `\t` should do the job. If not use html formatting

Comment: Thanks @rohit5k2 I will try that and see how it works.